# When will the summer 2019 transpacific sale begin (Hainan and others)?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

Everyday, I look at the prices for a flight from North America to Asia starting in June and ending in August. For the past 5 years, I would start looking in November everyday, and invariably there would suddenly be a sale, and I would by my air tickets.

For some reason, the sale has not yet come, and prices have remained high in comparison to previous years. I have a search that trys basically any city in North America to any city in East Asia departing mid-June and returning in late-August.

Let's take [Hainan airlines](https://www.hainanairlines.com/US/US/Offer?FOCUS_ELEMENT_ID=1055) for example. They have a fare sale that offeres a flight from Las Vegas to Beijing for $461 - but it requires return flight by June 30.

My specific question is, based on previous years, **when should we expect Hainan Airlines to start its sale for July/August?** My more general question is, when will other airlines follow suit?

Comment: I'm trying to ask specifically when Hainan's sale will begin. I didn't see a Hainan tag. Should one be created?

Comment: Note to close voters: this isn't a shopping question. It's not asking for price comparisons; it's asking when a specific airline sells discounted tickets.

Comment: Is it possible to predict that with any certainty?

Comment: @Traveller Perhaps somebody watched Hainan airlines every year, and knows the trends? I will ask this in my question. I have always bought earlier than now, then someone in May says "check out these prices!"